# Change value from outside of the function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have something like the following:

```
function somefunc() {
   function anotherfunc() {
      ...
      if ( m > ... 
      ...
   }
   $(window).on("scroll", anotherfunc);
}

somefunc();
```

I want to be able to change `m` value in execution of `somefunc("value")` (last step in above code snippet - `somefunc();`), so it would transfer the `m` value to the `anotherfunc` - but I don't know if I can(able) do so and would like to ask some for your help.

Comment: I believe that if you declare `m` outside the function it is also accessible inside the function. So add `var m = 1;` (or some other value) before the functions. (If I'm wrong people, please correct me)

Comment: @LinkinTED Could you please show me an example of this? I'm not sure what you mean as even if I'll declare a global `m`(outside of the functions) how would I be able to pass the variable through `somefunc` to `anotherfunc`?

Comment: see my answer...

Comment: don't use global or overlapped scope variable(s), instead try using .bind function .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function somefunc(m) {
       
    function anotherfunc() {          
        console.log(m)   
    }
    $(window).on("scroll", function(){
        anotherfunc(m);
    });
}
somefunc(1);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, but how could I pass the `m` value declared in `somefunc();`? If I'll use `somefunc("1");`, and use `function somefunc(m) {` it will be still `m = 0`.

Comment: @godoyehap you mean like this?

Comment: Yeah, just instead of `anotherfunc(m)`, I want to bind it to the scroll event with `$(window).on("scroll",`

Answer (score 0):

Like commented, declare `m` outside the functions:

```js
var m = 1;
console.log('Outside functions: ' + m);
function someFunc() {
  m += 1;
  console.log('someFunc: ' + m);
  function otherFunc() {
    m += 1;
    console.log('otherFunc: ' + m);
  }
  otherFunc();
}
someFunc();
```